# C++ preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, qt, c-preprocessor

I have a macro which defines the model number of an equipment.  I am having problems determining how to compare it to a string.

In a customer's specific header I have defined my macro as follows:

```
#define FTP_MODEL_NUM CT1030
```

Here I want to conditionally compile a section of code depending on the model number but no matter what value my macro has it compiles it anyway:

```
#if FTP_MODEL_NUM == CT1031  
    QMessageBox * lolers=new QMessageBox;  
    lolers->setWindowTitle(tr("title"));  
    lolers->setText(tr("this is test"));  
    lolers->show();  
#endif
```

What am I missing? Do I absolutely need to compare it to another macro when using the `==` operator?  I'm using Qt on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming C++'s preprocessor works the same way as C99's, what you're trying to do can't work.  After `FTP_MODEL_NUM == CT1031` is expanded to, e.g., `CT1030 == CT1031`, any identifiers remaining in the expression are replaced with 0, yielding `0 == 0`, which is always true.  I believe the standard way to do what you're trying to do is to define a macro with the same name as the model number (e.g., `#define CT1030`) and then implement the test with `#ifdef CT1031`.

Answer (score 2):

You cant lexically compare macros afaik. Only numerically. Define a second macro with numbers and use that.